# Bash Restrict parent script command line arguments carry forward to child scripts arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell

We have parent bash script

parent_source.bash

```
#!/bin/bash

source child_test.bash
```

Inside the child_test.bash

```
echo $@ 
#Doing some validation checks for $@, for child_script command line arguments are optional
```

Where as when executing

```
 source parent_source.bash one two
```

The child script is taking "one" and "two" in the $@ so validation is failing, It is not considering as zero arguments given to child script. Child script assuming it got 2 command line arguments.

But if we give command line args for child also It is working fine.

Could Someone please help us

Thanks

Comment: We have So many export statements in the child_test.bash export PYTHONPATH export PATHS etc, If we use ./ these are not reflecting in the current shell, We have to use source only. Is there any possibility to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing the [source](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Source_command) command, you actually injecting the content of `child_test.bash` to your `parent_source.bash` script, and then, when the first line in the `child_test.bash` is being executed, ie:

`echo $@`

It actually refers to the arguments passed to the parent script since the scope of the command is actually on the `parent_source.bash` script.

I suggest to execute the script without injecting the content to the parent script.

Something like this:

**parent_source.bash**:

```
#!/bin/bash

./child_test.bash
```

**child_test.bash**:

```
echo $@ 
#Doing some validation checks for $@, for child_script command line arguments are optional
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply But We have So many export statements in the child_test.bash export PYTHONPATH export PATHS etc, If we use ./ these are not reflecting in the current shell, We have to use source only. Is there any possibility to achieve this.

Comment: You can use `set --` before sourcing the child script.

Comment: It is working for me great, Is there any solution to fix in the `child_test.bash` instead of parent script. Generally we will deliver child scripts customer will write their own script to source all child scripts with some extra operations.

Comment: If you'd do it in the child, how the child'd know whether you provided arguments directly to it, or inherited from the parent?

Comment: I am sorry, not sure will it be possible to identify the direct or inherited args. If possible we can solve somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `$@` option to pass the values of `parent_source.bash` to `child_test.bash`

parent_source.bash

```
#!/bin/bash

source child_test.bash $@
```

Inside the child_test.bash

```
echo $@
```

Where as when executing

```
 source parent_source.bash one two
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of `source`-ing the child script from parent, the environment of parent script's shell is being propagated to the child script's content too.
So, the arguments given to the parent script is available and expedtedly being expanded with `$@` on child script.

You can save the arguments to parent script in an array and then unset the positional parameters before sourcing the child script to prevent them from being available to the child. So your parent script can take the form:

```
args=( $@ )
set --
source child_test.sh
```

Comment: It is working for me great, Is there any solution to fix in the child_test.bash instead of parent script. Generally we will deliver child scripts other users will write their own script to source all child scripts with some extra operations